# Как правильно писать: "вы пишите" или "вы пишете"?

Tags: глаголы

В последнее время часто вижу, что в интернете одни пишут "вы пишите", а другие "вы пишете". Почему ошибаются с написанием глагола?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Пишите"** и **"пишете"** - два разных слова, почти как **"компания"** и **"кампания"**, **"Иран"** и **"Ирак"**.

**"Пишите"** - это глагол в повелительном наклонении, он указывает, что нужно делать, и произносится с ударением на второй слог: **пишИте**.

**"Пишете"** отвечает на вопрос *"что делаете?"* и произносится с ударением на первый слог: **пИшете**.

Можно привести множество примеров, в которых оба глагола будут присутствовать в одном предложении. Например:

> Вы пишите об этом еще, мне нравится то, как вы пишете.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае возможны оба варианта. Через *и* пишется глагол в повелительном наклонении: т.е. просьба или приказ. Через *е* пишется глагол множественного числа второго лица.